# Film about someone trying to convince others that he is immortal

Tags: story-identification, movie, immortality

I saw this film years ago, but I can't remember the title. The whole film happens inside a room, it's about a guy who tries to convince others in the room that he is immortal (or maybe very, very old). I remember the film blew my mind, but somehow I can't remember the title. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Not immortal in the sense that it cannot be killed, immortal in the sense that it doesn't age ( die by natural means )

Comment: Yep, absolutely awesome movie! (It's The Man from Earth I think)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This could be the 2007 movie [*The Man from Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_from_Earth):

> The plot focuses on John Oldman, a departing university professor who claims to be a Cro-Magnon (or Magdalenian caveman) who has somehow survived for more than 14,000 years. The entire movie is set in and around Oldman's house during his farewell party, and the plot advances through intellectual arguments between Oldman and his fellow faculty members. The movie is composed almost entirely of dialogue.

Comment: This is my guess. Its an indie movie, fairly low budget, but god, they made the most of it.

Comment: The writer, Jerome Bixby, originally used the same plot idea in [TOS Star Trek, Requiem for Methuselah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requiem_for_Methuselah).

Comment: I removed the now obsolete link. There is no need to link the full movie, but you can add a trailer (if any), or a scene - something that won't be taken down or deleted.